# Buggy edges in three.js when using gltf

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Does anybody know how to get rid of this bug?

[image: Edges are buggy]

It doesn't occur on stuff created in three.js code (as for example the tree is not a .gltf but handcrafted code). However, the "sheep-like" thing I imported through a gltf (exported by blockbench) and I mean yeah - this looks completely inacceptable. I tried different scales but the edges are bugged no matter what scale I set the sheep to.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

  loader.load( './sheep.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

    var gltfO = gltf.scene;
    //gltfO.scale.set(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
    gltfO.position.set(0,-sz/2,0);
    scene.add( gltfO );

  }, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

  } );
```

Comment: It also occurs with antialias turned off so that's not the issue.

Comment: No it also happens when antialias is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is an issue with UV Mapping. At least I figured out a work around that one can apply in blockbench. Instead of just painting the rectangle in the UV you also need to paint the border OUTSIDE the rectangle. Not really a solution but it's at least a workaround. Probably doesn't work for non unicolor texture? I don't know. But it works in this case.